# Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access

I am trying to implement sparse matrix by using linked list.

The error showed that Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8) in the following c++ code.
The error may come from visiting the access had been released.But I can not debug it.

The usage of the code is:

input(row,col,value)
//input the sparse matrix dimension.Value is the nonzero terms.
4 5 6
//Next step when I'm trying to input the sparse matrix.
//the format is (row,col,value).
1 2 3
// error come from here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

struct Triple{
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
};

class Matrix;

class Matrixnode{
    friend class Matrix;
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &is,Matrix &matrix);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,Matrix &matrix);
    
private:
    Matrixnode *right;
    Matrixnode *down;
    bool head;
    
    union{
        Matrixnode* next;
        Triple triple;
    };
public:
    Matrixnode(bool b,Triple*t){
        head=b;
        if(head){right=down=this;}
        else triple=*t;
    };

    
};

class Matrix{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is,Matrix& matrix);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,Matrix& matrix);
public:
    Matrix(){
    
    }
    int max(int a,int b){
        if(a>b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;
    }
private:
    
    Matrixnode* headnode;
};

istream &operator>>(istream &is,Matrix &matrix)
{
        Triple s;
        cout<<"input(row,col,value)"<<endl;
        is >> s.row >> s.col >> s.val;
 
        int p=matrix.max(s.row,s.col);

        matrix.headnode =new Matrixnode(false,&s);
    
        if(p==0)
        {
               matrix.headnode->right=matrix.headnode;
               return is;
        }
        Matrixnode **head = new Matrixnode*[p];
 
        for (int i=0;i<p;i++)
               head[i]=new Matrixnode(true, 0);
 
        int currentRow=0;
        Matrixnode *last=head[0];
 
        for(int i=0;i<s.val;i++)
        {
               Triple t;
               is >>t.row>>t.col>>t.val;
               if (t.row>currentRow)
               {
                       last->right=head[currentRow];
                       currentRow =t.row;
                       last=head[currentRow];
               }
               last=last->right=new Matrixnode(false,&t);
               head[t.col]->next=head[t.col]->next->down=last; \\error!!!!
        }
 
        last->right=head[currentRow];
        for (int i=0;i<s.col;i++)
               head[i]->next->down=head[i];

        for (int i=0;i<p-1;i++)
               head[i]->next=head[i+1];
    
        head[p-1]->next=matrix.headnode;
        matrix.headnode->right=head[0];
        delete[]head;
        return is;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,Matrix &matrix){
    Matrixnode *headnode=matrix.headnode->right;
    
    while(headnode!=matrix.headnode)
    {
        for(Matrixnode *cur=headnode->right;cur!=headnode;cur=cur->right)
        os<<cur->triple.row<<","<<cur->triple.col<<","<<cur->triple.val<<endl;
        
        headnode=headnode->next;
    }
    return os;
}




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    Matrix m;
    cin >>m;
    cout <<m;
}
```

Comment: Union??? Why? That's asking for problems.  And why is there a max in the matrix class? Is `std::max` not good?

Comment: @JHBonarius The reason why is there a max in the matrix class is because the istream needs to use.

Comment: @Henry Your `Matrixnode` constructor needs to set all of the member variables (i.e. `right` and `down`), regardless of the `if` condition.  Even if you have to set those pointers to `nullptr`, they need to be set.

Comment: Are you setting next anywhere without using next (should also be initialized) :  head[t.col]->next=head[t.col]->next->down=last; \\error!!!